# Can get into Django project admin fine but blog is getting an error loading page

Tags: python, django, heroku, watson

I'm getting the error below trying to open my Django app in Heroku. It seems to have deployed successfully and is working from my local pc totally fine. I'm hoping this a simple fix. Thanks

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://djangowaston.herokuapp.com/

Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/blog/views.py" in post_list
  30.         data = json.dumps(tone_analyzer.tone(post.text, content_type='text/plain', sentences=None, tones='emotion', content_language=None, accept_language=None), indent=1)  # converting to string and storing in the data

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: tone() got an unexpected keyword argument 'content_type'
```

Comment: in settings did you add the new hosting domain?

Comment: What's the `tone_analyzer`? Is that your code or library code?

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I believe so
https://github.com/EdemD/djangoWatson/blob/master/mysite/settings.py

Comment: @WillKeeling tone_analyzer is a Watson API

Comment: What are the arguments types does `tone_analyzer.tone` expects and in what order? The exception it is thowing is very clear, but we can't help without any code.

Comment: @WillKeeling tone_analyzer is a Watson API. It's returning a different json when working on my pc than after I posted the code on Heroku to host the app. I play around with the errors and get it working. That was a bit strange but I'm a novice. Thanks